# Why does my TP link adapter disconnects from the AP when I change the mac address of wlan1

Tags: wireless, virtualization, mac, clone

I have TP-Link TL-WN722N WiFi Adapter(Atheros Chip).

I have tried changing mac address of using macchanger and some inbuilt commands.

But every time I connect to the AP, the Wifi Adapter disconnects and the MAC reverts to Original State and then connects again.

I am changing MAC to bypass MAC filtration

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote me on this, but the router recognises your device using the mac address. If you change this, your router won't be able to send packets to your device. As for it changing back, maybe some setting for Mac address is on auto.